# Extract words in pandas dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I select part of string in a data frame's column satisfying the following conditions?

- if the row contains `www`, then extract word after the first `.`
- if the row does not contains `www`, then extract word after `//`

Example:

```
Column

https://www.test.com
https://train.co.uk
```

In the first case I should extract the word after the first full stop, i.e. `test`; in the second case, I should consider the first word after `//`, i.e. `train`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is try to get the domain

```
import pandas as pd
import tldextract


df['domain'] = df.Column.map(lambda x : tldextract.extract(x).domain)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use regex with non-caption group:

```
df.Column.str.extract('//(?:www\.)?([^\.]*)')
```

Output:

```
       0
0   test
1  train
```